# Sort/order a string array by two conditions (name sequence and date)- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Having some issues trying to sort/order this string array.  There are thousands of files names that come back in the response, below is an example of 10.

```
array = [
'ORDERHEADER_010122.arc',
'ORDERITEM_010122.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010122.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010222.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010322.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010222.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010322.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010422.arc',
'ORDERITEM_010222.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010422.arc'
];
```

A simple `array.sort()` takes care of half of the issue as it will alphabetize the strings and inherently sort the dates.

What am needing is a "sequence" order of sorts along with the date order. So `prioSequence = ['ORDERHEADER', 'ORDERDETAIL', 'ORDERITEM'];` would be the sequence I want to see.

Expected output as:

```
array = [
'ORDERHEADER_010122.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010122.arc',
'ORDERITEM_010122.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010222.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010222.arc',
'ORDERITEM_010222.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010322.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010322.arc',
'ORDERHEADER_010422.arc',
'ORDERDETAIL_010422.arc'
];
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Extract the relevant parts. Sort accordingly... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Use `split()` to split the string into two parts. then compare the date first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix the string with the parts that determine the sort, i.e. yymmdd and 2 letters from the "ORDER" string, as it turns out that when you pick the 7th and 8th letter of those words (EA, ET, TE), they will be sorted correctly. Then after having sorted the items, remove that prefix again.

Here is how that works out:

```js
let array = [
  'ORDERHEADER_010122.arc',
  'ORDERITEM_010122.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010122.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010222.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010322.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010222.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010322.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010422.arc',
  'ORDERITEM_010222.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010422.arc'
];

let sorted = array.map(item => 
    item.replace(/ORDER.(..).*?_(..)(..)(..).*/g, "$4$3$2$1") + item
).sort().map(s => s.slice(8));

console.log(sorted);
```

#### Extending it

If you have more prefix-words of which you want to control the order, then create an array of those in their expected order. The solution will then turn that array into a lookup map (giving a 4-character sequence number for a given word). The call to `replace` then needs a callback argument, that will make the lookup and prefixes that sequence. Here is the code for that:

```js
let array = [
  'ORDERHEADER_010122.arc',
  'ORDERITEM_010122.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010122.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010222.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010322.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010222.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010322.arc',
  'ORDERHEADER_010422.arc',
  'ORDERITEM_010222.arc',
  'ORDERDETAIL_010422.arc'
];

let priorities = [
    'ORDERHEADER',
    'ORDERDETAIL',
    'ORDERITEM',
];

// Map the priority array to an object for faster look-up
let priMap = Object.fromEntries(priorities.map((word, i) => 
    [word, ("000" + i).slice(-4)]
));

let sorted = array.map(item => 
    item.replace(/(.*?)_(..)(..)(..).*/g, (all, word, dd, mm, yy) =>
        yy + mm + dd + (priMap[word] ?? "----") + all
    )
).sort().map(s => s.slice(10));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: wow, def. works as expected.  I guess I'm going to have to read up on regexp as I have no idea what is happening in that replace.  :) Is /ORDER.(..).*? looking at everything after ORDER?  i.e. HEADER, DETAIL or ITEM?  Maybe the three (..) after the _ is the mmddyy of the date string?  either way, this is a great jump-off point as there are other files in another API that have department level codes in the filename string. i.e. ORDERHEADER_1987_010122.arc.  REALLY appreciate your help here!!

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. The four captured groups (that have the parentheses), are put in reverse order (`$1` refers to the first capture group, `$2` the second -- which is the day part of the date, `$3` the month, `$4` the year). And to correctly order by date, the year should be put first, ...etc. True, for other input formats, you'd have to use a different breakdown, but it is always possible.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the further explanation.  Would it be possible to alter your code to allow a priority array?  After digging deeper through the thousands of records, it looks like there are more variations of ORDERHEADER/DETAIL/ITEM.  For instance, I see hundreds that have ORDHED and ORDDET.  I also see some with prefixes like PPS_, PPM_, PPA_.  Another example would be PPM_ORDHED_7200_110122.arc.  Would it be something like ```/PPM_.(..).*?_(....)_(..)(..)(..).*/g. $5$4$3$2$1```?  OR should I just create another question since the initial ask has changed?

Comment: Sure addition to answer.

Comment: Excellent! I did have some issues when modifying the priorities array as well as the main array when the priorities have underscores in them.  I suspect the underscores are throwing off the regexp.  I was able to get it working by modifying the beginning of the regexp.  Here is a codesandbox link where I was doing the testing. 
 [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-waterfall-tq5utm?file=/src/index.js). thanks again for your time!!

Comment: Good to hear you can apply it to your particular case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a custom compare function for your sorting method call. And, that method should first compare dates, and then (if a date is the same) order prefixes according to your requirements

Here is my example

```
const order = new Map() // one can use plain Array + Array#indexOf later on
  .set('ORDERHEADER', 0)
  .set('ORDERDETAIL', 1)
  .set('ORDERITEM', 2)

const compareFn = (a, b) => {
  const [a1, a2] = a.split('_')
  const [b1, b2] = b.split('_')

  const r2 = a2.localeCompare(b2) // TODO: re-write to date comparison a2 vs b2

  if (r2 !== 0) return r2

  return order.get(a1) - order.get(b1) // or Array#indexOf as mentioned above
}

// usage
array.sort(compareFn)
```

Comment: I like this a lot and I think it better fits what I mentioned about being able to define a priority listing.  To your point about using a plain array `array = ['ORDERHEADER', 'ORDERDETAIL', 'ORDERITEM'];` and then replace `order.get(a1)` and `order.get(b1)` with `order.indexOf(a1, 0)` and `order.indexOf(b1, 0)`, correct?  Thanks!!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken about the intended order, but this doesn't sort the date part correctly.

Comment: You are correct.  For instance, 010218 would sort higher than 011014.  I think the appeal of this answer was defining a sort priority.  I think this one would require a substring out the mmddyy and comparing from there.

Comment: @trincot good catch. One has to sort dates appropriately then, simple string comparison won't work out here